# NuxtJs Auth with local strategy

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, jwt, nuxt.js

I'm creating an app with nuxtjs and I'm using the nuxt/auth module. Everything is working fine, I'm using the login with Local strategies with JWT Token. The problem that I'm having is that if I close my browser and re-open the browser and if the token has not expire I'm logged in automatically. How can I disable this? I would like it so that when the user closes the browser the token is no longer valid?

Is it because of the Local Storage?? I guess that Nuxt/Auth stores the token in the localstorage? I also see it creates a cookie with the token but the expiration of the cookie is set to "Session".

Any clarification/help on how to this work would be greatly appreciated.

Regards.

CES

Answer (score 0):

Localstorage has no expire date you need to delete it manually.

Cookies have one like JSON web tokens.

What i do is following:

If my token lasts for 1 day i set the cookie lifetime also to 1 day. After 1 day the browser erases the cookie automatically. If you login after 2 days the cookie will be erased and you wont be automatically be logged in

Sure if you logout you need to erase it manually

In addition i also like to set HttpOnly flag on the cookie so my server can only read it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `destroyed hook` in main `nuxt component` for calling `logging-out` method.
When you leave the main component, like closing the tab and closing the browser, it will be logging out, but not recommended.
the better solution is set `lifeTime` when you are saving in `LocalStorage`.

Comment: thanks, but not sure how to set the lifeTime with the nuxt/auth module. Do not see that option listed in the docs.

Comment: you have to set a time as secounds format like 3600 + new date as scounds. then each time you reload, check the current time with saved time, if it was bigger, call logging-out.